# Google Cloud SDK "Curl Unrecognized"

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How do I use the curl command with my local Google Cloud SDK? Is it even possible? curl seems to work just fine with Google Shell in my browser, however I'm too new to this to call local files from the shell (I don't know if you even can).

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>curl --help 
>   'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have installed `Google SDK` on a Windows machine and you want to know why you are not able to run `curl`

`curl` is not installed automatically when you install the Google SDK, it works in the Google Shell because it is already installed, as well you would be able to find it on many Linux machines, but it depends on the particular Operating System and its release/configuration, therefore you should check if it is installed and if not present install it.

You can follow for example [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/objectstorage/restrict_rw_accs_cntainers_REST_API/files/installing_curl_command_line_tool_on_windows.html) guide to install curl in a Windows machine or run `sudo apt-get install curl` to install it on a Ubuntu instance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the `curl` binaries for Windows; which are available [here](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/).

Answer (score -1):

Curl is not enabled by default on the `GCP SDK` so you have to edit the `php.ini` file.

Have a look at `php.ini` at [PHP.ini SDK doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/php_ini) for how to enable `curl` (or equivalent) on the `SDK`